# https://example.com and https://www.example.com: Should I use one or two SSL certificates?

Tags: https, security-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am in the process of enabling HTTPS on my web sites. I have a web site, let's call it `example.com`, which is [available both with and without a `www.` prefix](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/66960/46459).

I can now:

1. request one SSL certificate for `example.com` and another one for `www.example.com` or
2. request a single SSL certificate for `example.com` with a [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) for `www.example.com`.

I am aware that, from a security point-of-view, both solutions are fine (which is why I ask this question here instead of at security.stackexchange.com). Certificate renewal will be automated and the certificates themselves are free of charge (using Let's Encrypt).

**Is there any reason to prefer one option over the other?**

Comment: Is there a reason that the site is available with www and without? If you 301 redirect one to the other, this entire issue disappears.

Comment: @IvovanderVeeken: How would this issue disappear if I 301 redirected one to the other? As far as I know, SSL verification is performed by the browser *before* executing redirects.

Comment: Never mind, I was getting a few details mixed up. The SSL handshake happens before the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to order the one cert for example.com. The www is part of it or included by default. If you wanted other sub-domains, ie server.example.com, then you would either need a wildcard domain cert [*.example.com] or order two to cover the extra domain. Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: As a small niggle, since OP specified "Let's Encrypt", it's probably worth mentioning that the inclusion of "www" as a default SAN might not be automatic (depending on the method used to obtain the certificate). Also, "Let's Encrypt" won't technically be offering wild cards till January 2018. Otherwise, good info. =)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason to prefer one option over the other?

Assuming the use of Let's Encrypt and that each certificate lists just the www and non-www versions of a single domain, the only likely drawback to using a SAN certificate is the possibility of some [compatibility issues with older browsers, mostly prior to 2003](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm).

On the positive side, there would be only a single certificate to automate for each primary domain (e.g. *[www.]example.com*). However, you might still want separate certificates for true sub-domains (e.g. *sub.example.com*) in case they need to be updated... so this could be a tossup benefit-wise.

As a purely personal opinion, I see no reason not to use a SAN certificate in this instance unless browser compatibility is a priority.

Comment: Thanks. Since we have other domains on that IP as well, we will use SNI, and, thus, older browsers won't be supported anyway.

Comment: Welcome. Glad to be of assistance. =)

Comment: SAN certificates have wider support than SNI.    Assuming that you are going to host both on the same server, a single SAN certificate would be preferable to two certs served with SNI.   If you are on a shared host with lots of other sites you are going to be using SNI no matter what though.